# imagemagick with grayscale not working

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to change a file named "anvil_base.png" to grayscale so I am using imagemagick. What I am entering is `convert anvil_base.png -colorspace Gray -gamma 2.2 anvil_base.png`

but it is just returning this

`Invalid Parameter - -colorspace`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are on Windows and you have not put the directory where ImageMagick is installed ahead of other directories in your PATH. You have three choices:

**Option 1**

As Glenn kindly points out, if you are using ImageMagick version 7 or newer, you can use the new name for `convert` which is `magick`, like this:

```
magick image.png -colorspace gray ...
```

**Option 2**

Use the **full** path to ImageMagick every time, something like this:

```
C:\ImageMagick-6.9.3\convert ...
```

**Option 3**

Change your PATH. So you would need to do:

```
Start->Programs->Control Panel->System->Advanced
```

and then choose `Environment Variables` and change `PATH` so that it looks like:

```
PATH=C:\ImageMagick-6.9.3;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32
```

The main thing is that ImageMagick directory is at the start of the PATH. Then Windows will find the `convert` which is part of **ImageMagick** before it finds the built-in Windows `convert` program which converts FAT filesystems to NTFS. If you choose Option 3 above, you need to either log out and back in again, or start a new Command Prompt for the new PATH to become active.

Comment: To clarify, it means you are running some other program on your computer that is called "convert".  Fixing the path as suggested is a good solution.  Also, with recent ImageMagick installations you can use the "magick" command instead of "convert".  The name of the command was changed for this very reason.  I don't remember exactly when that happened; it isn't mentioned in the ChangeLog.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thank you - I forgot that option! D'oh!