# How to remove yellow dots gif

Tags: gif, photoshop

i need remove all the yellow dots.

I removed white background in photoshop and save it for web and they are still here, if I set a black background in browser.

the same effect happend if I add new layer in photoshop ...

[screen from photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P027I.png)

Comment: Are you looking for Photoshop support? Or do you want to write some software? This is a programming questions site.

Comment: I am looking for help with that problem, probably with som graphic sw ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is also available for OSX and Windows. Just in the Terminal window at the command-line:

```
convert globe.png -fuzz 10% -fill gray -opaque "rgb(232,235,144)" result.png
```

[image]

That says... *"open "globe.png" and find any pixels that are within 10% of rgb(232,235,144) and fill them with mid-grey, saving the result as "result.png"*

Of course, you can fill the dots with another colour by changing the word `gray` to `pink` or any other `rgb()` colour you like!

Comment: it does not work, it write me invalid parameter - -fuzz

Comment: You probably have to use `10^%` or `10%%` on Windows.

Comment: You may not have set your PATH correctly... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634927/2836621

Comment: I try both of options but it still does not work ... why? Here is a screen from console
[link](http://test.docasne.eu/cmd.PNG)

Comment: Try `convert /?` and see if you are running **Windows** `convert` or **ImageMagick** `convert`.

Comment: convert working, i tried some example from imagemagick web, but I afraid, that second parameter (fuzz in this case) will doesn't work ...

Comment: Try a simple example first with the picture in your current directory. If that doesn't work, please show screen shot of error message.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't work anymore but yesterday it work, i am not sure with the directory but it works ... but now, it doesn't ... [here](http://test.docasne.eu/cmd1.PNG) is the link ...  I run as administrator and no change ... What should I do?

Comment: You are still running Windows `convert`, not ImageMagick `convert`. Please run `echo %PATH%` and show the output. You must have the directory containing ImageMagick's convert **before** `Windows\system32`

Answer (score 0):

GIF has indexed colors. If you use the classic dialogue save for web. You can manually assign a color to a table indexed color. Like this: http://sklad.bereza.cz/00-jarda/00_screenshot/2016-06-18_174624.jpg

The problem is that the GIF has a limited number of colors and some colors consists from several different colors. By assigning a color to a table you stop composing and is used direct color.